# Why does this subclass code cause a runtime error?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a base class `A` that I am extending with `X`. Inside of `A` there is another class, `B`. It seems like the virtual method is not being defined, but I don't understand why?

```
class A {
 public:
  class B {public: bool value;};

  A() {}
  B b_;
  void DoStuff(B& b);
 private:
  virtual void DoStuffImpl(B& b) = 0;
};

class X : public A {
 public:
  X() {}
  void Trigger();
 private:
  virtual void DoStuffImpl(B& b);
};

void A::DoStuff(B& b) {
     DoStuffImpl(b);
}

void X::Trigger() {
    DoStuff(b_);
}
void X::DoStuffImpl(B& b) {
    b.value = true;
}

int main(){
    X x;
    x.Trigger();
    return x.b_.value;
}
```

P.S. This came up because I am having a different problem with my code, but I couldn't even make this toy example work, so now I have this making me curious....

Here is a link to the above code, which is compiling and failing to run: http://ideone.com/mBJ1Kg

Comment: It can't cause a runtime error if it doesn't run.

Comment: BTW you should initialise that `bool` member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It runs fine. ideone reports a "runtime error" with an exit code of 1 because you return `1` from `main`. A non-zero return code is conventionally considered to be a failure.

If you comment out your `return x.b_.value` line and replace it with `return 0` then [everything's fine](http://ideone.com/JXbXTj).

You could have put some `std::cout` lines in there to see what's going on, and see that the program works! :D

Comment: Dang, you're right! My very large C++ program is failing to compile because it can't figure out `B` in my `X::HelperFunction(B& b)`. But I can't seem to create a toy example that exhibits the same behavior.... Anyway, thanks

Comment: @RobertMartin: `RESOLVED/OOPS_BROKEN_TESTCASE` :)

Comment: yup. Allow me to slink away and create another toy. Video related: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnjfuKVCHFw